# как хранить данные о лайке

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я создал сервер где храню данные локально. Сейчас я хочу перевести хранение данных в бд. У меня есть сущность "книга", у него есть поле likes с типом данных Set like, где были id пользователей. Но теперь я хочу в бд создать новую таблицу где будут хранится идентификатор книги и пользователя. А У "книги" будет числовой тип столбца likes. Смогу ли я потом присваивать полю лайков в книге их число, в зависимости от того сколько их в третьей таблце?

Comment: Вы эта... не надо делать схему БД, высасывая её из пальца. Фигня получится. Проанализируйте нормально предметную область и составьте ER-диаграмму. Оттуда и таблицы, и их структуры, и связи - всё само вылезет.

Comment: @Akina я пытаюсь ее сделать. Просто не понимаю как мне составить ее, потому не понимаю как хранить столбец с лайками у таблицы книги

Comment: Никак. Сущность "лайк" является одновременно связью между сущностями "юзер" и "книга". А посему должна быть представлена отдельной таблицей, хранящей ссылки на указанные таблицы, возможно, с дополнительными полями